# How to fetch specific data from a list

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a method that fetches all the users from the firebase database, and then I store all the users inside a list.
let's say my list is:

```
    user1 = User(
    id: 1
    name: "john"
    car: false
   )

    user2 = User(
    id: 2
    name: "kim"
    car: true
    )

 userList = [user1,user2]
```

How do I get the id of the user based on the name for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the simplest ways is using forEach(), which needs a function as argument:

```
class User{
  final int id;
  final String name;
  final bool car;

  User({this.id, this.name, this.car});
}

void main() {
  User user1 = User(
    id: 1, 
    name: "john", 
    car: false
  );

  User user2 = User(
    id: 2, 
    name: "kim", 
    car: true
  );

  List<User> userList = [user1,user2];

  userList.forEach((user){
    if(user.name == "john")
      print("ID: ${user.id}");
  });
}
```

But you have more options, look up this list [Top 10 Array utility methods you should know (Dart)](https://codeburst.io/top-10-array-utility-methods-you-should-know-dart-feb2648ee3a2)

This way you can get all the johns:

```
List<User> johns = userList.where((user) => user.name == "jhon");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the where on a list to filter it out. Example:

```
 var userList = [user1,user2];

 var kimList =  userList.where((f) => f.name == 'kim').toList();

 kimList.forEach((u) => print( '${u.name } - ${u.id}')); // will contain all the users where name is kim
```

References

- [Filter List](https://riptutorial.com/dart/example/31185/filter-a-list)